# Jquery on click ads a variable to the link

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

My blog has its posts links. What I need is code that will do this: when a user clicks on a post link, a parameter will be added to the link which I'll use with a get function on the other page.

This is my link - link which is visible and indexed by google:

```html
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/post1/">my post link</a>
```

When a user clicks on it, I need a way to add `?car=type` to the link, `http://www.mysite.com/post1/?car=type`.

I'd like to do this with jQuery.

P.S.
I can't just add my car variable to the links in normal html, becouse Google will index them badly, the variables change every day and I'd get pages not found all over the serps.

Any idee?
Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
       this.href += "?car=type";
    });
});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/y6PrF/

Comment: Will this affect my google index? I mean I don;'t want my links indexed with the cat variable, thx:)

Comment: No, Google bots aren't smart enough to detect such a thing as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you mark the desingated links in a way such as a class (say `addType`):

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/post1/" class="addType" >my post link</a>
```

you can do something like this on document load, no need to wait for click to do it:

```
$(function() {
   $("a.addType").attr("href",function() {return this + "?car=type";});
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nbKPu/

Comment: Ty very much, which solution is better?

Comment: both will probably work. I guess that my class tagging makes it more targeted and allows you to filter which links are being modified better.